# Update Telerik ComboBox and RadGrid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

I have inherited an application that uses telerik controls. This is my first time to work with it and I'm a little confused.

I have a RadComboBox that has its values hard coded. When the user selects an item, a RadGrid is refreshed to show the records that correlate with the item the user selects from this combo box. This all works great.

I'm trying to create link buttons, so that when the user clicks on one, the RadComboBox value is changed to whatever value I set it to in the codebeind page and the RadGrid is refreshed to show the appropriate records.

I can set the value of the RadComboBox, and see what value it has when debugging, but the RadComboBox in the browser does not reflect the change and the RadGrid is not refreshed when I programatically execute the event handler for it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using to change the value of the `RadComboBox` so far? Is it a client-side or server-side change?

Comment: So you are using the client API or server API?  What's your code look like?  I've used the combo box (both client and server) and not have had an issue like this, so we need more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the site is using Telerik's components, then it's likely using their AJAX components as well, like the `RadAjaxManager` and `RadAjaxPanel`. Make sure that the LinkButtons are included in the ajax manager's settings:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server" UpdatePanelsRenderMode="Inline">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="btnSomething">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="ddlSomething" />
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="grdSomething" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>  
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

Comment: Can I use a regular old ASP:Linkbutton or would I need to use a telerik control?

Comment: You can use a regular LinkButton, you just need to include it in the ajax settings if the other controls are ajaxified, like in the above example.